# The compressed public key byte header

Tags: cryptography

I've noticed that compressed public keys are always either 0x02 or 0x03, but what exactly determines whether it's 0x02 or 0x03? I can go look at the OpenSSL code to answer this, but I'm hoping someone already knows the answer and can tell me :P

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out myself looking at the source. For those that want to know, the first byte of an OpenSSL EC public key has three bitflags. They have these semantics:

bit0 - tells you which y coordinate to use, bit1 - compressed, bit2 - uncompressed

So compressed public keys will always be 2 or 3 in the first byte, depending on which y coord is being used.

Comment: Could you elaborate and post it as a response, then accept it? That way we the question gets marked as complete.

Answer (score 3):

The public key format that OpenSSL and Bitcoin use is described in [SEP 1](http://www.secg.org/index.php?action=secg,docs_secg), published by the Standards for Efficent Cryptography Group on page 10.

> 1. Convert the field element x<sub>P</sub> to an octet string X of length ceil([log<sub>2</sub> q]/8) octets using the conversion routine specified in Section
>      2.3.5.
> 2. Derive from y<sub>P</sub> a single bit ȳ<sub>P</sub> as follows (this allows the y-coordinate to be represented compactly using a single bit):
> 3. If q = p is an odd prime, set ȳ<sub>P</sub> = y<sub>P</sub> mod 2.
> 4. If q = 2m, set ȳ<sub>P</sub> = 0 if x<sub>P</sub> = 0, otherwise compute z = z<sub>m-1</sub>x<sup>m-1</sup> + · · · + z<sub>1</sub>x + z<sub>0</sub> such that z = y<sub>P</sub>x<sub>P</sub> and set ȳ<sub>P</sub> = z<sub>0</sub>.
> 5. Assign the value 02<sub>16</sub> to the single octet Y if ȳ<sub>P</sub> = 0, or the value 03<sub>16</sub> if ȳ<sub>P</sub> = 1.
> 6. Output M = Y || X.

... and page 53 ...

> - If C is an octet string and the leftmost octet of C is 02<sub>16</sub> or 03<sub>16</sub>, parse the leftmost ceil([log<sub>2</sub> q]/8)+1 octets of C as an octet string R, the rightmost *maclen* octets of C as an octet string D, and the remaining octets of C as an octet string *EM*.
> - If the leftmost octet of C is 04<sub>16</sub>, parse the leftmost 2 * ceil([log<sub>2</sub> q]/8) + 1 octets of C as an octet string R, the rightmost *maclen* octets of C as an octet string D, and the remaining octets of C as an octet string *EM*.
> - If the leftmost octet of C is not 02<sub>16</sub>, 03<sub>16</sub>, or 04<sub>16</sub>, output “invalid” and stop.

So, in plain English:

- It can be 0x04 too. That's is the 'uncompressed' key. If you generate a key today, it won't create one of these. However, if you have an old wallet, you might have some. They are equivalent in security to compressed keys.
- Whether it's 0x02 or 0x03 depends on on the value of ȳ<sub>P</sub>. We can generate ȳ<sub>P</sub> instead of including the full y coordinate, which saves us a nice bit of space. That's what compressed keys are.

I'm not sure what q is in this context, if somebody wants to tell me in comments, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Parity determines if its 0x02 or 0x03

Node.JS:

```
if (y.isEven()) {
    publicKeyBytesCompressed.unshift(0x02)
} else {
    publicKeyBytesCompressed.unshift(0x03)
}
```