# Why are some public keys prefixed with 0x00?

Tags: transactions, public-key, ecdsa

ECDSA public keys seem to always start with `0x02`/`0x03`/`0x04`/`0x05` [1](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/11301/86692), followed by either 32 bytes of 64 bytes.

However, I encounter some public keys prefixed with `0x00`.

For example, the source output of transaction
[5c7c65bb950d3605cc67bd02c29e84cc14dfaa80626ef6a575132c7ce7979d2f](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/5c7c65bb950d3605cc67bd02c29e84cc14dfaa80626ef6a575132c7ce7979d2f) contains two public keys:

`037953dbf08030f67352134992643d033417eaa6fcfb770c038f364ff40d761588`

`0014fa6851313844da08b6a539aff5e74e705b7465fad0fc5ceeccae707995b846`

When fed into `EC_KEY_oct2key` function from OpenSSL 1.1.1, the second public key directly fails.

Another example is transaction [f0020466ca75caa648cdc8364f297bda7bb06329bec5305ffb59ea2ea348ac39](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/f0020466ca75caa648cdc8364f297bda7bb06329bec5305ffb59ea2ea348ac39), which uses an output that lists a public key like this:

`0029a38fa2eaf8e67481c47eeeaeb625e6d426eb78f3b9e0728a4679370ce5ac96`

These `0x00` public keys seem to always come with `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` and never block validation because some other public key would be valid.

What are these keys and what should a client do with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not keys, they are arbitrary data.

Until Bitcoin 0.16, an invalid public key was [allowed in the bare multisig](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.16/src/script/standard.cpp#L135), as long as it's the right size. With the upcoming 0.17, [this is no longer possible](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.17/src/script/standard.cpp#L81), and transactions like the ones you linked to will be considered non-standard (note that this does not prevent their inclusion in a block, and they are still valid if included).

People have often used such tricks to embed data in the blockchain. For instance, providing 1 valid and 1 invalid key in a 1 of 2 multisig allows someone to embed 33 bytes of data, without sacrificing the BTC locked up in the wallet.

A more extreme example of this is in tx [fc200f9cef8faf8f76756b5d02081061a1fd22ec1d580f778c12373e12a56016](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/fc200f9cef8faf8f76756b5d02081061a1fd22ec1d580f778c12373e12a56016), which contains "keys" like `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

(example tx from [this issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/14104))

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question: is disallowing invalid public keys an effective defense against this particular trick? As most 32-byte data are valid coordinates anyways, wouldn't it be rather straightforward to circumvent this restriction by using prefixing the arbitrary data with `0x02` or `0x03`?

Comment: @AndreasBlaesus Indeed, it is not a great defense. I haven't had time to check the code to see if it does any deeper checking (although I don't believe it can, off the top of my head). The change however does make it a standardization rule.